# Flask: How to convert a python dictionary to JSON?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a Flask app where I pass a dictionary as a parameter to the HTML page that I am rendering:

```
@app.route('/cyto')
def testfn():
    nodes={
    "nodes": [
            {
            "data": {"id": "a", "label": "Gene1"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "b", "label": "Gene2"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "c", "label": "Gene3"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "d", "label": "Gene4"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "e", "label": "Gene5"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "f", "label": "Gene6"}
            }
    ],
            "edges": [
            {
            "data": {
            "id": "ab",
                    "source": "a",
                    "target": "b"
            }
            },
            {
            "data": {
            "id": "cd",
                    "source": "c",
                    "target": "d"
            }
            },
            {
            "data": {
            "id": "ef",
                    "source": "e",
                    "target": "f"
            }
            },
            {
            "data": {
            "id": "ac",
                    "source": "a",
                    "target": "d"
            }
            },
            {
            "data": {
             "id": "be",
                    "source": "b",
                    "target": "e"
                }
                }]    
    }
    
    nodes=json.dumps(nodes, ensure_ascii=False)
    
           
    return render_template("cytoscape_result.html", nodes=nodes)
```

This is cytoscape_result.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.18.2/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <title>Result</title>
</head>




<body>
    <script>
        JSON.parse({{ nodes }})
    </script>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

However, JSON.parse({{ nodes }}) throws this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected property name, got '&'

When I inspect the line that causes the error, it looks like:

```
JSON.parse({&#34;nodes&#34;: [{&#34;data&#34;: {&#34;id&#34;: &#34;a&#34;, ...
```

I think the problem is that JSON.parse interprets the double quotes around the dictionary entries as the ascii code instead of actual double quotes. How do I tell JSON.parse to interpret them as double quotes? I tried setting ensure_ascii=False in json.dumps, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the dict to the jinja template and use the [tojson](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#tojson) filter to convert it into JSON.

```
@app.route('/cyto')
def testfn():
    nodes={
        "nodes": [
            # ...
        ],
        "edges": [
            # ...
        ]
    }
    return render_template('cytoscape_result.html', nodes=nodes)
```

```
<script>
const data = {{ nodes | tojson }};
console.log(data);
</script>
```